# React function uses outdated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, use-state, react-query

I am using [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) to fetch external data, based on the current state here is how the code looks like

```js
const Home = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [group, setGroup] = useState(1);

  const query = useQuery('/query', async () => {
    console.log(group);

    return axios.get('/query', { params: { group } });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries('/query');
  }, [group, queryClient]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setGroup(1)}>First group</button>
      <button onClick={() => setGroup(2)}>Second group</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

There are 2 buttons that changes the state (group), and when the state changes (useEffect) I invalidate old queries to send new queries but the problem is that the callback has only the initial state and not the updated state and when it get executed it prints out the initial state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should modify your `useQuery` section in this way

```
const query = useQuery(['/query', group], async () => {
    console.log(group);

    return axios.get('/query', { params: { group } });
  });
```

Comment: Maybe add some more info on why this change is correct